# Checkboxes with formspree

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to have checkboxes and use formspree? ([formspree)](https://formspree.io/). I've looked for examples and have tried giving the inputs a name and value attribute but nothing seems to work. I'm not even sure if its possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, they only support form text.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was worried about